# Using Task.Delay() closes program

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I try to use Task.Delay() but when the program gets there, it simpy closes itself no matter what. E.g in that case the program cant even reach the  `Console.Write("*");` line, it closes. What am i doing wrong? Any idea?

(Example code)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Whatever
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task WriteAsync()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                Console.Write("*");
            }

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WriteAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change it to `static async void Main(string[] args)` and use `await WriteAsync();` instead.

Comment: I dont want to use `await WriteAsync();` ,because its an infinite loop and i want it to run at the same the with other asynchronous methods.

Comment: Then write other asynchronous methods. If `Main` doesn't have any pending tasks to resume execution from in the event loop, it will immediately exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Patrick Roberts said in the Question comments, make your main method async.

It's helpful to know what's going on, so I'll try break it down.

`Task.Delay(1000)` returns a task, and that task must be awaited somewhere (and it is).

However the Task that's awaiting `Task.Delay(1000)` is returned by `WriteAsync` and the main method isn't awaiting that task (ergo the `Task.Delay(1000)` isn't actually being awaited anywhere).

The main method runs a method which returns a task, then - immediately - it exits, the work of the task could have started, but nothing is (a)waitng for it to finish, so the program terminates with that task unfinished.

Now in the main method you *could* have `WriteAsync().Wait()`.
However this isn't recommended for lots of reasons, but mainly because you're synchronously calling an async method, and while it will work with this simple program, it is a sure fire way to introduce deadlocks into your program.

Instead, change your main method to be async.
When writing async code, it needs to be [async all the way down](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#async-all-the-way)

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await WriteAsync();
    }
```

**Question** *So if I had numerous asynchronous methods in the main, at least one of them would have to be awaited, else the program would just finish before the tasks could run*

**Answer** No, all tasks would have to be awaited.

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        WriteAsync01();
        await WriteAsync02();
    }
```

If `WriteAsync02()` completes before `WriteAsync01()` the program will terminate before `WriteAsync01()` completes, which is not what you want.

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await WriteAsync01();
        await WriteAsync02();
    }
```

This will await both the tasks in sequence, So `WriteAsync01()` runs to completion before `WriteAsync01()` starts, this may not be what you want.

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task1 = WriteAsync01();
        var task2 = WriteAsync02();
        await task1;
        await task2;
    }
```

Will start both tasks, but the program will wait for both tasks to complete before terminating. Alternatively, this is identical to the above.

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task1 = WriteAsync01();
        var task2 = WriteAsync02();
        await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
    }
```

Comment: ["It's t̶u̶r̶t̶l̶e̶s _tasks_ all the way d̶o̶w̶n _up_"](https://xkcd.com/1416/)

Comment: I see! Thank you. So if I had numerous asynchronous methods in the main, at least one of them would have to be awaited, else the program would just finish before the tasks could run.

Comment: No, they would all have to be awaited. You want the program to run until ALL the tasks have completed. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Nitpick, the last two blocks aren't identical. For example if `task2` faults with an exception, the first block doesn't exit until after `task1` is complete, but the second block will exit as soon as `task2` is faulted.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, Fair nitpick :)

Answer (score 0):

Since `WriteAsync()` is not awaited in `Main` the Program continues after calling the async task and actually finishes before the Task is completed.